# Altering objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The following code is an example of my question:

```
Iterator<Person> currPerson = person.iterator();
while(currPerson.hasNext()){
    Person curr = currPerson.next();
    // Iterator<Person> currPerson2 = person.iterator();
    //EDIT
    Iterator<Person> currPerson2 = this.deepCopy.iterator();
    curr.moveLocation();
    while (currPerson2.hasNext()){
        Person curr2 = currPerson2.next();
        // if same spot
        if (curr.checkLocation(curr2)){
            int index = person.getIndex(curr2);
            curr.fight(person.get(index));
        }
    }
}
```

If I create another Iterator from the same arrayList, will any changes to the first Iterator affect the other; and make the while loop after moveLocation() work incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You're dealing with the same instances, you're just iterating over them twice.

Comment: This seems to me a bit like cowboy-coding. I suggest you change your business logic.

Comment: when you say currPerson2 = person.iterator();, you are only making another reference to the same object. If you would like to created a new array of objects you have to do percisely that: currPerson2 = new Iterator<Perso>();

Comment: I made some edits above. Say I had a method that made a deep copy and iterated that, if I used getIndex on the person ArrayList could I use that index to get a Person object for the fight() method?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish from a higher-level, and how this code applies to that?  This seems a tad convoluted, but that might be because we're missing the larger context.